# What does `$xml = $( xmlDoc )` do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsexml

In javascript / jQuery, the example on this [page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) contains the following code which I am struggling to understand;

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

Specifically the 3rd line;

```
$xml = $( xmlDoc )
```

What does that do? Does that form of syntax have a name that I can Google for to find out about it?

Also, in the code above they seem to be using the convention of prefixing variables that contain jQuery objects with a dollar sign. But if that's the case, then shouldn't the variable `xmlDoc` in the second line be `$xmlDoc` instead?

Comment: There's nothing special about the syntax. The variable named `$xml` is assigned the result of calling the function `$` with as its parameter the variable `xmlDoc`. It's the same syntax as `a = f(b)`.

Comment: "shouldn't the variable `xmlDoc` in the second line be `$xmlDoc` instead" - perhaps the author wanted to use `xml`/`$xml` but `xml` has been used already for the string. But nothing is mandatory about that.

Comment: @hvd So what does that line do?

Comment: @NigelAlderton My comment only addressed the syntax part. The syntax just means "call function `$`", nothing special. But I'm not qualified to comment on what that function does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It creates a jQuery object based on the xml specified above, enabling you to use jQuery's methods on it to find nodes and manipulate them.

Comment: Doesn't the previous line `xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml )` return a jQuery object? What does the previous line return?

Comment: $.parseXML(xml) returns an xml document, not a jQuery object

Comment: @Jeroen moons In this question; Could you please tell me; why all the four lines are comma separated (in single line)? This is not working when replace , with ;... :(

Comment: It's a compound var declaration, if you want to do that on separate lines you can do ´var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ); var $xml = $( xmlDoc );´ etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` symbol at the start of variable is purely just for naming convention (of jquery objects). It's a way of reminding you that this variable is a jquery object and can therefore have functions such as `find()` called on it.

`$.parseXML( xml )` doesn't create a jQuery object, its just using jQuery to parse the XML.

Comment: So you mean to say 'var jqXmlObj = $( xmlDoc )' is possible which is same as $xml = $( xmlDoc ) ??

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Yes, theres nothing special about having a dollar symbol in your variable name. `$xml` is no different to `foo` or `sau$age`

Answer (score 0):

It is to construct a jQuery object by a normal object. By doing this, you could use the jQuery method on it.

Comment: I don't understand. What's "the jQuery method"?